# Why am I receiving this error with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table named `products` with three columns: `prod_id`, `part_no`, and `name`. I am attempting to insert a row into this table by using the following:

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO PRODUCTS (prod_id, part_no, name)
   ...> VALUES ("123", "123", "Seismic Sensor");
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Error: table PRODUCTS has no column named name
```

Here is part of my `schema`:

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE products (
prod_id text PRIMARY KEY,
part_no text
name text);
```

Comment: Missing a comma after `part_no text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a comma when you're defining the schema - try

```
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE products (
prod_id text PRIMARY KEY,
part_no text,
name text);
```

Note the comma after `part_no text`

Comment: Thanks, surprised SQLite let me create the table in the first place with that error.